# GitHub Actions IdP Role assuming eks master role in pipeline

Tags: github-actions, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I am working on a GitHub Actions pipeline to build and deploy resources to my AWS EKS cluster. The master role for this cluster is `eksClusterRole`.

I have configured Github Actions to assume a role, `GH-Actions-EKS` (authenticated via IdP) which has permissions to assume the `eksClusterRole` (this is declared in `eksClusterRole` Trust Relationships).

However, when I fetch the kubeconfig and try to run a `kubectl` command, I get the error:

```
E0527 18:38:25.728495    1615 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0527 18:38:27.275337    1615 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0527 18:38:28.482227    1615 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0527 18:38:29.682448    1615 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

I am stumped as to why this is, I have set the proper IAM settings on the console side to let `GH-Actions-EKS` assume `eksClusterRole`.

I am able to access this cluster locally when I assume `eksClusterRole` with another user which is allowed to assume this role.

My GitHub Actions Pipeline:

```
jobs:
  kubectl-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [
        kustomize,
      ]
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    env:
      ENVIRONMENT: dev
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: kustomize-bundle-${{ env.ENVIRONMENT }}.yaml
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.AWS_ROLE_ARN_EKS }} # GH-Actions-EKS
          role-session-name: ${{ env.AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME }}
      - name: Update Kubeconfig
        run: aws eks update-kubeconfig --region ${{ env.AWS_REGION }} --name dev --role-arn ${{ env.AWS_EKS_CLUSTER_ROLE_ARN }} --verbose
      - name: Kubectl
        run: |           
          curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.27.2/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
          chmod +x kubectl
          mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
          mv ./kubectl ~/.local/bin/kubectl
          PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
          env | grep -i aws
          kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```